# Node js database release executed at the end

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, asynchronous

I never used Node js and was reading a little bit on it. Everybody is talking about the fact that you cannot predict in which order your code will be executed. But I don' know if I understand this correctly.
If I have the following code for example:

```
//my test code
  app.use('/test', (req, res) =>{
  dbpool.getConnection(function(err, conn){
         conn.query('select * FROM user', function(err, rows) {
              res.json(rows);
              conn.release();
         })
     })
  })
```

The last method I call is conn.release(); But If I understand it correctly. It is possible that this code is executed before my conn.query finishes? -> so it will result in an error, because the connection is closed and I still try to query the DB.

Is my mindflow correct here? Is it possible that conn.release() is executed first? If so. What would be an easy way to circumvent this, so the conn.release() get's only called after the conn.query is finished?

Comment: `conn.release` is called after the query is finished. The reason for this is because the callback you pass to  `query`  is called when the query is finished.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense that the callback function is only called when the original function finishes. So if you have to execute like for example 3 queries in a specific order. Would you need then to execute the first query. In the callback of the first query, the second query, and in the callback of the second query, the third query? Is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: That would be one way to solve it which would result in the so called _callback hell_. A way around this, are `Promise` chains which could further be improved by `async`/`await`. But even the calssic callbacks can be written without callback hell [like in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2v9rogL/2/)

Comment: Hello t.niese, that is a very cool example you gave there in the fiddle. Thank you!!!